# ActionSheet crash on iPad (camera button)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uialertcontroller

I'm having some troubles with my ActionSheet. On iPhone it works fine, but on iPad it just crashes.

I have a button to display the camera but I'm not able to do it correctly on iPad.

Code:

```
class pictureViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    @IBAction func choosePictureAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alertPictureFrom = UIAlertController(title: "De dónde sacar la foto?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        presentViewController(alertPictureFrom, animated: true, completion: nil)
        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cámara", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = .Camera
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Galería", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        picture.image = image
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

> Your application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.

Comment: You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says: "You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem" via the `popoverPresentationController`

This will allow UIKit to know where to present the popover from, and then you get that lovely behavior where the popover appears attached to the element you specify.

For example:

```
alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
```

Now that example is totally for demo purposes, you will need to figure out the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` for the popover.

Reference Documentation:

- [popoverPresentationController](http://file:///Users/andyo/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/popoverPresentationController)
- [sourceRect](http://file:///Users/andyo/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceRect)
- [sourceView](http://file:///Users/andyo/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceView)

Comment: This works for me the first time, however, if the ActionSheet is presented again, I receive the error again. I am setting the sourceView and sourceRect in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method prepareForPopoverPresentation.

Comment: Oh just figured it out. It works if I set the sourceView and sourceRect not in the delegate method. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try (in the case of a UIButton):

```
picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = testButton
picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = testButton.bounds
picker.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right.bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

your Error Genrate Due to UIActionSheet

> UIActionSheet not support in ipad.
>   for the iphone nothing to do in iphone UIActionsheet work fine
>   for IPAD UIActionSheet open in Another View like

```
UIActionSheetObjects.showFromRect(CGRectMake(150, 0, 300,200 ) ,inView:self.view, animated:YES)
```

and it will work for you...